HuggingFace's transformers I'm getting the message "Some non-default generation parameters are set in the model config"
I need help with a problem. The template works but I want to correct this message so that everything is correct. The purpose of this code is to save the model before training. It saves, but this message always appears in the terminal after running the code.
code:
from transformers import MarianMTModel, MarianTokenizer
from transformers.generation import GenerationConfig

model_name = 'Helsinki-NLP/opus-mt-tc-big-en-pt'

tokenizer = MarianTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = MarianMTModel.from_pretrained(model_name)

save_directory = 'initial_model'
tokenizer.save_pretrained(save_directory)
model.save_pretrained(save_directory)

Message after run this code:

Some non-default generation parameters are set in the model config.
These should go into a GenerationConfig file
(https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/generation_strategies#save-a-custom-decoding-strategy-with-your-model)
instead. This warning will be raised to an exception in v4.41.
Non-default generation parameters: {'max_length': 512, 'num_beams': 4,
'bad_words_ids': [[54775]], 'forced_eos_token_id': 44670}

I've looked at the documentation, but the information is all too simple and doesn't cover the whole problem

I think you just need to follow what the link says and create a GenerationConfig and save it to same save_directory as your model (i.e. https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/generation_strategies#save-a-custom-decoding-strategy-with-your-model).

Get the same error even when following the instructions in the link.
